# Listings alternative

Tags: listings

Well like the title says I am asking if there is an alternative to the `listings` package. With more programming language definitions and the likes, and updated definitions for the current languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the [`minted`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted) package. It uses the external `Pygments` python syntax highlighter and is therefore quite powerful. You need to use the `-shell-escape` option to allow it to call the required external executables.

Comment: While I like minted (its output is also significantly nicer), it's worth noting that it does slow down compilation noticeably.

Comment: @Antal: There should be, at least in theory, the possibility to cache the formatted output generated by `Pygments`. The author of the `minted` package should include that in some future version. However, the project web site states that the package is currently not really maintained.

Comment: In `t-vim` (ConTeXt module), I cache the results by creating an md5 hash of each file, and calling the formatter only if the file has changed. So, subsequent runs are relatively fast. The functionality is actually part of the `mtxrun` (the lua script that runs ConTeXt), and `t-vim` only provides an interface to that.

Answer (score 5):

And there are GNU Source-highlight:
http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/
and hightlight:
http://www.andre-simon.de/

They can export LaTeX code.

---

PS.
In ConTeXt, there is a [`t-vim` module](http://modules.contextgarden.net/vim), which calls VIM to highlighting the program code.