# LaTeX Django template custom language for listings

Tags: listings

I'm using `Listings` package to insert python and javascript code into my thesis. This package has a lot of languages but not Django Template.

Someone has yet defined that custom language, or there's another method to include it, as pretty as would be with `listings`?

Comment: The Ruby equivalent of Django template language is called Liquid. You could search for that, although "liquid latex" gives entirely useless results...

Comment: If "Django template" is [the language mentioned here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/), it looks very much like HTML (for which there exists a `language=HTML` style in [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)).

Comment: @Werner It is the language mentioned in your link. However, even though it is mostly HTML it has variables, filter, tags, etc. I think he also wants these specific Django template syntax highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get more syntax highlighting than is provided by the HTML style of `listings` then you could do one of the following:

- Extend the HTML style with the extra [Django template keywords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) you need. See [Extend a language with additional keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28229/extend-a-language-with-additional-keywords)
- Define a new language style in `listings`. See section 4.18 Language Definition in the [`listings`](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) manual.
- Explore a more powerful syntax highlighting package like [`minted`](http://code.google.com/p/minted/). `minted` includes support for regular Django templates (`html+django`) and for templates written in Jinja (`html+jinja`). See answer to [Listings alternative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11810/4278)