# Java Code in a paper

Tags: formatting, code, java

I am writing a paper and would like to include some of my "real-world" Java code. What is the best way to accomplish this? I would like to see two templates:

1. My explanation to the right of my Java Code in a column fashion
2. All of my Java code pasted in one block and then a description afterwards

I think 2 is probably the best way to go for simplicity.

Comment: Have a look at the `listings` package. Also useful to search here for [listings] (could possibly include the word java in your query, but answers for other languages will probably also be useful).

Comment: another alternative might be [minted](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11808/15717),you can search here by the tags `listings` and `minted` to narrow down search results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `listings` package like this sample:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{_myperl.pl}
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<@ARGV>)
  { $sum += 1/($_*$_); }
print sqrt(1/$sum), "\n";
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\section{listings}
\lstset{language=Perl}
\lstinputlisting{_myperl.pl}
\end{document}
```

Here I have included the sample java code in the document, but you will probably want to keep it in a separate file.

[image: output]

Comment: Um, that's Perl :-) (Same idea applies of course, but might slightly confuse people.)

Comment: I'm trying this and my code is spilling over the page?